# Method in angular is not definable

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a personal project still trying to learn Angular.
I am facing this issue.

Error:(11, 89) ng: Member 'd' is not callable
Error:(19, 42) ng: Member 'c' is not callable

My Code is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">Modal</div>
            <!-- Large modal -->
            <div class="card-body">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(content)">Large modal</button>
                <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button (click)="c('Close click')" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example, reproducing the issue? You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one

Comment: basically the problem is in calling function in (click)="c('Close click')"

Comment: It would be really hard to understand what's wrong until you provide your Component Class code. Hence, the request for a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue.

Comment: i haven't used that before let me try to put my code their and then comeback to you

Comment: can you add definition of the function `c` i.e. your `ts` file?

Comment: these are ng-bootstrap functions

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/brrpkkmrlxrl?file=app%2Fmodal-config.html
thats what i am using from ng-bootstrap @SiddAjmera

Comment: Appears to be working perfectly in your Sample StackBlitz.

Comment: Yeah but i don't know Why in My compiler JetBrains WebStorm 2018.3.5 x64

Comment: Should I ignore that?